# updating UI with a volley request from a different class

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-volley

I am having trouble with volley (again).  I want to run a volley request in a class, so more than one activity can feed off its results and update their UI's accordingly.  I have got it return data and call the request from the UI but now im struggling to update the UI with the new data.  I have looked at answers but I'm trying to understand the structure and I am at a loss, can some please advise/ talk me through it

Comment: "now im struggling to update the UI with the new data" - how are you struggling?

Comment: I'm unaware of what Volley is, though, it sounds like you need something like a `BroadcastReceiver`. Or if you're happy using a library, something like  `EventBus` is perfectly sound?

Comment: Hi it doesn't update the information with data collected.  It loads the view and the retrieves the data, and  then stops, but does not insert retrieved data in to the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming I understand what you mean as being:

***A Volley request returns, updates some data set through some activity***

In this case, assuming the calling activity contains everything, and reminding that this is a **very general** example, what you should usually do (usually, since there are exceptions to the case), is just insert the data into the data set contained in your UI holder (e.g. your recycler adapter) and update it, an example would be your adapter holding a method similar to this:

```
public void updateDataSet(List<Item> items)
{
    //mItemList is the adapters member list
    if (null != mItemList)
    {
        mItemList.clear();
        mItemList.addAll(items);
    }
    else
        mItemList = items;

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

you call this inside the request callback you fired earlier, just make sure to initialize everything BEFORE you fire the request, e.g.

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
 {
     Log.d(TAG + ": ", "somePostRequest Response : " + response.toString());
     // here you need to parse to JSON to a list and then call...
     List<Item> items = parseResponse(response);
     myAdapter.updateDataSet(items);
  }
```

Now, if what you meant was

***A Volley request returns in some Activity, I want it to update stuff in another place***

there are a couple of options:

1. As someone said in the comments - you could go for `EventBus`.
2. You could hold a DataManager class, which would be a global singleton, in which case you can either hold the data and update it there, and then every activity (in it's onResume or other relevant lifecycle method) knows to pull that data.
3. You could do the same as option 2, with the exception of that DataManager holding a reference to other UI parts (e.g. Fragments), and triggering member methods in them that pass the data and trigger the updates.

Personally I find option 3 cumbersome and somewhat bad practice, but if all else fails, (and it shouldn't, but if it does) then you can try.

There are more options out there, it depends and varies according to the data, your app architecture, coding style and other stuff you apply.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is very helpful, I will try some of the techniques and see which one works for me.   - (it was the second part of the answer that is relevant) sorry for my babbling question, i was very stressed at that point haha.  Many thanks for you input and time

Answer (score 0):

You can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). To use EventBus you need to register class where you will receive update and when you publish event for those event all classes will receive it.
[image: Flow Diagram]

Here is an example using greenrobot's EventBus :

Event Model :

```
public class MessageEvent {
     /* Additional fields if needed */ 
}
```

Subscribe :

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);  // In Activity onCreate method

@subscribe
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event){
    // this is the method to receive event
}
```

Publish event :

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

Now every class subscribed for this event model will be updated.
Note : subscribed classes have to alive, If anyone destroyed they won't receive update.